# Django не регистрирует модель в админке

Tags: django

model.py

```
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name="Заголовок страницы")
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=PathRename("new"), verbose_name="Фото под заголовком")
    pretext = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст цитаты")
    block1_title = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Заголовок")
    block1_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Подзаголовок")
    block1_text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст")
    block2_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Подзаголовок")
    block2_item1 = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст пункта 1")
    block3_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Подзаголовок")
    block3_text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст")
    block4_subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name="Подзаголовок", blank=True)
    block4_text = models.TextField(verbose_name="Текст", blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Новости"
        verbose_name_plural = "3. Новости"

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "Новости"
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(News)
class NewPageAdmin(TranslationAdmin):
    form = NewPageForm
    fieldsets = (...)
```

forms.py

```
class NewPageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        widgets = {
            "title_ru": SummernoteWidget(),
            "title_en": SummernoteWidget(),
        }
        fields = "__all__"
```

makemigrations pages и migrate выполнил.

В админке должен появиться пункт "3. Новости", а его нет.
Что сделать, чтобы он появился?

Answer (score 1):

Проверить что ваше приложение зарегистрировано в settings.py INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: да, зарегистрировано и modeltranslation тоже